# Editar un Json con js

Tags: javascript, java, nodejs, paginación, knex

Hola amigos tengo un json, que obtengo de un query de mi db, entonces estos resultados los quiero paginar, entonces encontré que con esto:

```
  $.ajax({

        url: '/pag-news',
        type: 'GET',
        data:{
            page: 2,
            pagelimit: 10
        },
        success: (data) =>{

            console.log(data)

        }
    });
```

puedo dividir en partes el query que hago, pero tengo un problema, esto funciona cuando mi json tiene un objeto **data** en donde están los "datos" de mi query. Pero el Json que obtengo es array simple...

algo como esto:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_proyecto": 1,
        "id_usercreated": 2,
        "img1": "29f64cb637e74b83dfe9e0e233650293f967.jpg",
        "img2": "1322fa112dc68747273a6829cb24b7396392.jpg",
        "img3": "4b486476009f64182898f5832c6b6aeb9144.jpg",
        "imgh": "129ef14087792fc7ff7e2190f4776faa9a1c.39",
        "text1": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestin",
        "text2": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesti",
        "text3": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingt",
        "title": "x",
        "created_at": "2019-03-25T12:14:33.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "id_proyecto": 1,
        "id_usercreated": 2,
        "img1": "a8bbc858c3372ad3c22b92a2c4c59339cf1c.jpg",
        "img2": "134d0a991a175a6c88aca94366ae365a4c80.jpg",
        "img3": "b85bf288fda6dab3e9a6e25dc8da09dc1751.jpg",
        "imgh": "746672798b3f91ff040397b4929947616982.jpg",
        "text1": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestin",
        "text2": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesti",
        "text3": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingt",
        "title": "Noticia 2 de prueba",
        "created_at": "2019-04-03T06:45:03.000Z"
    }
]
```

En consola se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera es modificar mi Json para todos los datos estén dentro de un objeto `data: {}` y mi Json lo obtengo de aquí

```
const query = knex().select('*').from('NEWS_');
    query.then((data)=>{
        data.forEach((data) => {
            news.push(data);
          });

          res.json(news);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Hola podrias probar let response = {}; response.data = news; rest.json(response); y ver si te funciona.Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con una simple modificación:

```
const query = knex( ).select( '*' ).from( 'NEWS_' );
  query.then( ( data ) => {
    res.json( { data: data } );
  } ).catch( ( err ) => {
        console.log( err );
  } );
```

Con eso obtendrás algo como esto:

```
{
    data: [ {
        "id": 1,
        "id_proyecto": 1,
        "id_usercreated": 2,
        "img1": "29f64cb637e74b83dfe9e0e233650293f967.jpg",
        "img2": "1322fa112dc68747273a6829cb24b7396392.jpg",
        "img3": "4b486476009f64182898f5832c6b6aeb9144.jpg",
        "imgh": "129ef14087792fc7ff7e2190f4776faa9a1c.39",
        "text1": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestin",
        "text2": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesti",
        "text3": "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingt",
        "title": "x",
        "created_at": "2019-03-25T12:14:33.000Z"
    },
  ...
```

Como ves, no es necesario copiar un *array* en otro, basta con asignarlo directamente a la clave `data` de un nuevo objeto. Y, como en JavaScript los objetos se usan mediante referencias, el proceso es prácticamente instantáneo y con nulo conste tanto de procesado como de memoria.

Comment: SI quedó, pero aún tengo una cuestión, no puedo dividir por limites mi query, hay alguna forma de meterlo en en otro hijo y llamarlo page  o ya demería estar dividido el json en secciones?. Me refiero a esta parte > data:{
            page: 2,
            pagelimit: 10
        },